# Applying Definition Query for multiple features using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, python-script-tool, definition-query

I'm trying to apply the following code to extract features that contain these letters 'MW' within the field called 'CODE' for multiple layers. But I'm getting a SyntaxError for line 5 (defintion query).

```
import arcpy  
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current")  
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)  
for layer in layers:  
    if layer.supports(definitionQuery)  
         layer.definitionQuery = ""CODE" LIKE "('%MW%')"
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the formatted syntax error?

Comment: Are you trying to extract the features, or update the map?

Comment: Try removing the parentheses. e.g. `"""CODE LIKE '%MW%'"""`. You may also have to add quotes around CODE depending on the field and data type. I'm not sure if [arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm) works on layers.

Answer (score 5):

You need a colon after your line:

```
if layer.supports(definitionQuery)
```

should be:

```
if layer.supports(definitionQuery):
```

You should also consider modifying your query as was commented by @smiller. It will make your code easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, both the colon and the parentheses of my definition query solved the problem!

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept the answer so others know you found it useful.